# Syntax for glmer function for use with glmulti?

Tags: r, lme4, glmulti

Using `glmer`, I can run a logistic regression mixed model just fine. But when I try to do the same using `glmulti`, I get errors (described below). I think the problem is with the function I am specifying for use in `glmulti`. I want a function that specifies a logistic regression model for data containing continuous fixed covariates and categorical random effects, using a logit link. The response variable is a binary 0/1.

Sample data:

```
library(lme4)
library(rJava)
library(glmulti)

set.seed(666)
x1 = rnorm(1000)  # some continuous variables 
x2 = rnorm(1000)
x3 = rnorm(1000)
r1 = rep(c("red", "blue"), times = 500)  #categorical random effects
r2 = rep(c("big", "small"), times = 500)
z = 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2 +2*x3       
pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))         
y = rbinom(1000,1,pr)      # bernoulli response variable
df = data.frame(y=y,x1=x1,x2=x2, x3=x3, r1=r1, r2=r2)
```

A single glmer logistic regression works just fine:

```
model1<-glmer(y~x1+x2+x3+(1|r1)+(1|r2),data=df,family="binomial")
```

But errors occur when I try to use the same model structure through glmulti:

```
# create a function - I think this is where my problem is 

glmer.glmulti<-function(formula, data, family=binomial(link ="logit"), random="", ...){
  glmer(paste(deparse(formula),random),data=data,...)
}

# run glmulti models
glmulti.logregmixed <-
  glmulti(formula(glmer(y~x1+x2+x3+(1|r1)+(1|r2), data=df),   fixed.only=TRUE), #error w/o fixed.only=TRUE
      data=df,
      level = 2,              
      method = "g",            
      crit = "aicc",           
      confsetsize = 128,       
      plotty = F, report = F,  
      fitfunc = glmer.glmulti,
      family = binomial(link ="logit"),
      random="+(1|r1)","+(1|r2)",  # possibly this line is incorrect?
      intercept=TRUE)

#Errors returned:
singular fit
Error in glmulti(formula(glmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1 | r1) + (1 | r2),  : 
  Improper call of glmulti.
In addition: Warning message:
In glmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1 | r1) + (1 | r2), data = df) :
  calling glmer() with family=gaussian (identity link) as a shortcut     to lmer() is deprecated; please call lmer() directly
```

I've tried various changes to the function, and within the `formula` and `fitfunc` portion of the glmulti code. I've tried substituting `lmer` for `glmer` and I guess I don't understand the error. I'm also afraid that calling `lmer` may change the model structure, as during one of my attempts the `summary()` of the model stated `"Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']."` I need the glmulti models to be the same as what I'm obtaining with `model1` using `glmer` (ie `summary(model1)` gives `"Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']"`

Many similar questions remain unanswered. Thanks in advance!

Credit:

sample data set created with help from here: 
  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46523/how-to-simulate-artificial-data-for-logistic-regression

glmulti code adapted from here:
[Model selection using glmulti](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952828/model-selection-using-glmulti)

Comment: I've tried your code and it runs with the one line changed into `random="+(1|r1)+(1|r2)"`. However the script doesn't stop. There are `warnings()`, telling `calling glmer() with family=gaussian (identity link) as a shortcut to lmer() is deprecated`, even when you change both `glmer`s into `lmer`s. So I assume `glmer()` is called within `glmulti()` somewhere. Package `glmulti` was last updated 2013, maybe you need to find and alternative or create something new with lmer().